# How to switch to a different xdg-desktop-portal?

Tags: debian, command-line, gnome, xdg

In my machine I, have multiple xdg-desktop-portal

```
$ ls -la /usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/portals
.rw-r--r-- 100 root 23 Mar 14:48 gnome-keyring.portal
.rw-r--r--  99 root 20 Mar 02:25 gnome-shell.portal
.rw-r--r-- 548 root 18 Oct  2022 gnome.portal
.rw-r--r-- 495 root 29 Nov  2022 gtk.portal
```

What is the command to switch to a different xdg-desktop-portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xdg-desktop-portal` is an interface that allows applications to communicate with the desktop environment, it is not something that can be switched between different implementations using an environment variable.

> An XDG Desktop Portal (later called XDP) is a program that lets other applications communicate swiftly with the compositor through D-Bus. It's used for stuff like e.g. opening file pickers, screen sharing.

The different portal implementations you see in the `/usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/portals` directory are different portal backends provided by different desktop environments. Each portal backend serves as a bridge between the application and the corresponding desktop environment.

To use a specific `xdg-desktop-portal` implementation, you would typically need to use a desktop environment that provides that implementation. The desktop environment you are currently using determines which portal backend is used.

If you have multiple desktop environments installed on your machine, you can switch between them by logging out and choosing a different desktop environment at the login screen. Each desktop environment will come with its own default `xdg-desktop-portal` implementation.